# Meaning of the workflow Event Log?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

What is the meaning of the below sharepoint 2007 log?

Log:
The previous instance of the timer job 'Config Refresh', id '{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}' for service '{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}' is still running, so the current instance will be skipped.  Consider increasing the interval between jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Means a job is schedule to run, say, every 30 minutes, but when the *next* one was going to run the *previous* **was still running** so it could not start and was skipped.